# How can I enable special Fn-Keys on my on lenovo s206 (e.g. touchpad on/off)?

Tags: mouse, 13.10, touchpad, lenovo

I can turn the touchpad off in the mouse settings, but two things won't work:

- The "disable while typing" option
- The standard on/off button for the touch pad won't work (it's the one with the little touchpad symbol crossed off, on the F6 key). I've tried any of the following combinations:

  - <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>
  - <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>
  - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>
  - <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>
  - <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>.

Almost all the other keys of that kind work, like brightness control, volume control, Wifi toggle, but this one and the mic off and camera off won't work.